# Issue with window.closed in IE when PDF opened with window.open()

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pdf, popup

I have a problem when I try to check state of the popup window in IE.

```
function openPopup(url)
{
    myWindow =  window.open(url, "_blank", "resizable=1,status=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0");
}

function checkPopup()
{
    console.log('Is closed : ' + myWindow.closed);
}
```

If I call **openPopup('http://someUrl.org/someHtml.html')** and after a while call checkPopup() everything works fine and I'll get **"Is closed : false"** into console, but when I call **openPopup('http://someUrl.org/somePdf.pdf')** and after a while **checkPopup()** function I get "Is closed : true" into console.

It seems to IE creates new window with pdf in it, instead of use window that created by window.open()

Could anyone help me? How can I get real state of popup with PDF document in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by use embedded iframe in popup window:

```
function openPopup(link) {
    var html = "<html><head><title></title>";
    html += "</head><body style='margin: 0;'>";
    html += "<iframe height='100%' width='100%' src='" + link +"'></iframe>";
    html += "</body></html>";
    win = window.open("", "_blank", "resizable=1,status=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0");
    win.document.write(html);
    return win;
}
```

Comment: At a glance, this doesn't seem to print right if I ctrl+p in Chrome.